# 32-bit PAE - Only 2 GB of ram recognized, 4 GB installed

Tags: 14.04, 32-bit, ram

There are a lot of this question and still I don't have an answer, so maybe I give it a shot asking the question. I recently bought a 2 GB RAM and put it into another DIMM slot. So now I have 4 GB, which on 2 GB module each. I am using 14.04 32 bit.

1. BIOS recognizes 4 GB, not memtest, not live CD, not inside OS itself.
2. `lshw` recognizes a total of 4 GB, max 8 GB.
3. CPU is Athlon II P360, PAE is supported.
4. Now, GPU is 512 Mb, and according to `dmesg`, GTT / GART is 1 GB enabled

I only see 2 GB of total RAM. If, and if GPU is tapping into system host, than I still have more than 2 GB RAM.

I recognize some answer about 32 bit OS, but it still has to recognize RAM beyond 2 GB. (almost the answer on the net suggesting PAE kernel, it's not necessary anymore). Also, I, in turn, took of each module to test, and it both works, and the system still only recognize 2 GB RAM.

Any ideas?

Comment: Suggested title change: "Only 2 GB of ram recognized, 4 GB installed." --- much more informative

Comment: It seems like a waste of time to recommend installing Ubuntu 64-bit in case it doesn't recognize all your RAM either, but it wouldn't hurt to at least try running the Ubuntu 64-bit live DVD.

Comment: not that i want it, but i am using ath9k on my wifi, which in 64bit usually there's a lot of problem, thank you though, i will download the 64bit and give it a try, but, just for the sake of curiousity, this problem has effect on so many ubuntu user, and it has to solved in some way

Comment: Regarding the ath9k wireless driver take a look at this link: http://askubuntu.com/search?q=user%3A19421+ath9k.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Ubuntu use all my 4GB of RAM?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/482828/can-ubuntu-use-all-my-4gb-of-ram)

Comment: PAE does not work on all systems, even if the BIOS reports 4GB installed, the chipset and BIOS and CPU all have to actually support addressing that memory with PAE, and the majority of old 32-bit systems were never tested or certified for PAE use. Read [PAE Sucks by Linus Torvalds](http://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=76912&curpostid=76973), quote _"PAE didn't ever really fix anything.
It was a mistake. It was just a total failure"_

Comment: i understand Linus comment about PAE and 64bit OS (which all of us should migrate years ago, but memory are not the cheapest thing back then). But again, the barrier is 4 (up to), and I believe a lot of people succeed in having more than 2GB in their 32bit OS (in fact, my arch enemy "Win7", show more than 2 gig in this laptop). 2.5 or 3 is not too much to ask, is it? I am hopeless that this matter will resolved on 32bit OS, and the only way to do is having 64bitOS, but others can, why can't I?.and 1 more thing, the duplicate q's has more than 2gig isnt he?

Comment: well, I installed 64bit 14.04 and still only 2 gig on monitor....this is sad

Answer (score 3):

Well, I found the culprit... to other users, do not buy two modules of RAM of different brands. This was solved by buying 2 of the same brand, same specs, of 4GB, now I have 8GB. Thank you for comments.

Here is a similar question regarding RAMs with different Bus speed

- [Is it safe to use RAM sticks with different frequencies?](https://superuser.com/q/52340/134448)

Comment: and oh, 32bit OS recognize 4GB RAM !!. Not recommend installing 32bit OS even you have that much, but it does work..Not all computers, but yeah, it worked !